# Same file_temporary_path for localhost and production server?

Tags: 7, configuration

Each time I move one of my Drupal website from localhost to production server or vice-versa, I have to edit my `settings.php` to update the path of the temporary file directory:

```
# $conf['file_temporary_path'] = '/home5/dawnings/public_html/fw2/tempdir';
$conf['file_temporary_path'] = 'c:/Temp/Drupal/tempdir';
```

Is there a way to specify a unique relative path to this temporary file directory once for all and which would work both for localhost and production server? The objective is to avoid having to update my `settings.php` anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is more than 1 way to accomplish something like this. I am not aware of a simple "1 line universal fix" unless you try a relative path, but that assumes *some consistancy* between your servers which clearly by your directory paths you dont have.

Option 1:

At the bottom of you settings.php put something like:

```
$local_settings_conf = dirname(__FILE__) . '/settings.local.php';
if (file_exists($local_settings_conf)) { include $local_settings_conf; }
```

I do this programmatically in BASH with like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# I actually install drupal via the command line with a custom install
# profile and append on the tidbit to settings.php programmatically like
# so ...

cd $drupal_www_dir
drush site-install MY_INSTALL_PROFILE \
  --locale=en \
  --db-url="mysql://dev_user:dev@localhost:3306/demo_drupal" \
  --account-name=admin \
  --account-pass='admin' \
  --acount-mail=foo@test.com \
  --site-name=demo --verbose -y


#
# Now that drupal is built we modify the settings.php file with additional db
# and other custom configuration values by appending a child seetings file.
#
# This is in concept similar to an Apache vhost directive file.
#
echo "altering settings.php to be aware of our 3rd party remote databases."
sudo chmod -Rv a+rw "${drupal_www_dir}/sites/default"
read -r -d '' PHPCODE <<'EOF'
/*
 * For our project we provide our own localized configuration schemes.
 */
$local_settings_conf = dirname(__FILE__) . '/settings.local.php';
if (file_exists($local_settings_conf)) { include $local_settings_conf; }

EOF
echo "${PHPCODE}" >> "${WWW}/sites/default/settings.php"
```

Then for each server you keep a version of this file. Or in this file make an If-Else PHP block that stores the correct `$conf` value based on whether this configuration file is `$local` vs `$dev` or `$prod`. So basically you can move all your custom settings.php stuff that arent 100% stock drupal into a special appended configuration file ... this way the stock drupal settings.php stays as it is and all your custom stuff can go into its own file as-needed.

Option 2:

Use something like the [Environment module](http://drupal.org/project/environment) and in PHP set the value for the `file_temporay_path` with variable_set as that is what is being called by [file_directory_temp()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_directory_temp/7).

Those are the two options I know of that aren't brain surgery ...

**EDIT 09/26/2014 by author**

- You can also use Drush on each server to run: `drush vset file_temporary_path "to/some/path"`
- If you're comfortable with virtualhost settings you can also always create a aliased directory in your webserver configuration (pushing the problem up 1 level in the production stack (out of PHP))